# Artifactory nuget push - non-existing user (API key / access token)

Tags: nuget, artifactory, nuget-server

I am able to push nuget packages to Artifactory using `dotnet nuget push %WORKSPACE%\NuGetPackages\*.nupkg --source <url> --api-key <username>:<encrypted password>`. However, I would like push using a API key or an access token, but I receive *403 Forbidden* trying to do so. Is it possible to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NuGet protocol expects the API key to be `username:password`. You can use the Artifactory API key instead of the password, but you still have to provide the username, as described as a fourth option in [the API docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Authentication).

Comment: For some reason, I did not get any notification. But thanks, I will try it out.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!